# Supply current for AD5754R

Tags: dac

Supply current of [Ad5754R](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5724R_5734R_5754R.pdf) is not mentioned on the datasheet. How to calculate the supply if it is not mentioned on the datasheet ?

Comment: Page 5, section "Power Requirements".

Comment: @ThePhoton I went through those, but I didn't understand which parameter to consider

Comment: There are three different power supply pins, AVss, AVdd, and DVcc. They give you the current for each one individually. They give it per channel, so you need to multiply by 4 (unless there's a channel shut-down feature, then multiply by the number of channels not shut down). Then add whatever current will be drawn by the load to either AVdd (if the output is sourcing) or AVss (if the output is sinking).

Comment: If you need more guidance than that, please edit your question to include your schematic, showing how you're powering the chip, and what is connected to the outputs.

Comment: @ThePhoton I am searching for Dc/Dc converter for powering this Chip, I haven't concluded schematic yet

Comment: @mightybeard well, we can't tell you how much a system will consume without knowing what you have in that system: If the DAC outputs say 1 V and you attach a 10 kΩ load to that, obviously, it'll draw an additional 0.1 mA to its other power consumption. If that load is 100 kΩ instead, it'll draw 0.01 mA. Without knowing what you attach to the DAC, how should we be able to tell you how to power it?